# Power Automate cannot update person to Sharepoint list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'm trying to update a sharepoint list with a person using Power Automate. Even though I can use "Resolve Person" successfully, I can't save the person to the list item and fails with "could not find list item".
I can update it if the flow is not within a "Apply to each" loop. 
Very frustrating!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

The error is regarding the list item, that means that someone delete the item ID=12 or the permissions have been removed. There's no errors regarding claims on your printscreen.